# How to install add-ons after the initial install of Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, istio

Grafana, service graph and zipking aren't deployed after the installation of Istio.There's no way to install these add-ons after the initial install of Istio??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how did you install istio.

if installed with helm install, then you can install add-ons using command like this:

```
helm upgrade istio istio-1.0.0/install/kubernetes/helm/istio --set grafana.enabled=true,servicegraph.enabled=true,tracing.enabled=true
```

or you installed with helm template, then you need to edit the values.yaml in your helm template directory to enable those add-ons, then install it:

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system > $HOME/istio.yaml
kubectl apply -f $HOME/istio.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** Tested with Istio **v1.9.0** installation with **istioctl** on Linux on **April, 2021**.

[Starting with Istio 1.6](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/addon-rework/#timeline), telemetry-related addons (Grafana, Prometheus, Zipkin, Jaeger, and Kiali) deployment manifests are located on `samples/addons/` directory.

To deploy all addons we can simply do:

```
$ kubectl apply -f ${ISTIO_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/samples/addons
```

In case you experience the following warnings/issues regarding Kiali's deployment:

```
unable to recognize "kiali.yaml": no matches for kind "MonitoringDashboard" in version "monitoring.kiali.io/v1alpha1"
unable to recognize "kiali.yaml": no matches for kind "MonitoringDashboard" in version "monitoring.kiali.io/v1alpha1"
unable to recognize "kiali.yaml": no matches for kind "MonitoringDashboard" in version "monitoring.kiali.io/v1alpha1"
...
```

simply re-apply Kiali's manifests:

```
$ kubectl apply -f ${ISTIO_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/samples/addons/kiali.yaml
```

This happens because some of Kiali's CRDs are not ready when needed.

For more information about, check [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/27417) GitHub issue.

Hope it helps ;).